# LD_PRELOAD with several source files

Tags: c++, linux, g++, ld-preload

I writed LD_PRELOAD module, all my sources are in `source.cpp`, but now i need to add `crypt.cpp` file with some classes i need, how can i compile LD_PRELOAD via g++ using more that one .cpp file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your command to build the preload library was:

```
g++ -fPIC -shared -o preload.so source.cpp
```

then you would change it to:

```
g++ -fPIC -shared -o preload.so source.cpp crypt.cpp
```

i.e. you simply add the name of the file to the end of the command line compiling the .cpp files.